# $gcd(p,a-1)$ or $gcd(b,p-1)$ where $p$ is a prime factor of $a^b-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a,b$ be positive integers and let $p$ be a prime factor of $a^b-1$.

Show that either $gcd(p,a-1)$ or $gcd(b,p-1)$ must be greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ does not divide $a$, Fermat's little theorem states $$a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$$

If $p$ divides $a^b-1$, we have $$a^b\equiv 1\mod p$$

This congruence rules out $p|a$, so we can apply Fermat's little theorem.

The order of $a$ modulo $p$ , the smallest number $o>0$ with $a^o\equiv 1\mod p$ must be a divisor of $b$ and of $p-1$.

If $gcd(b,p-1)=1$ , we have $a\equiv 1\mod p$ , hence $p|a-1$, so $p$ and $a-1$ cannot be coprime in this case.